# Nuxt3 - Route not Found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Before routing to any path it is showing but whenever my app contains some reloading, refreshing functions or even if I reload the website manually the nuxtapp is revealing 404 not found error.

So I actually gone through code, as my app contains a file **nuxt.config.js** with param:

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...,
  ssr: false,
})
```

While generating static files of the app (**npm run generate**) , I tried to launch in my localhost (**npx serve .output/public**) which is not having any problems, but in Network section of the Develop Console (browser: Firefox) shows up a singular error, saying the route is not found, but in website there is no any error which should be showed up like in Network section.

Comment: First question, do you need SSR/SSG or SPA-only is enough? Second, do you have a [repro]?

Comment: I only need SPA, and I think its happening somewhere in my nginx.conf